# Mockito Android throw verify error but I not call verify at all

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I write a lot of unit test when running individual test case it fine. But when I try to run all test cases in class it throws a weird error.

**The test case**

```
@Test
fun `case-4 Do get new list data after refreshing refresh is gone`() {
    false `should equal` false
}
```

**The error**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.MockitoKt.verify(Mockito.kt:248)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()
```

**My Environment**

```
testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0'
testImplementation 'org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.30'
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
```

Comment: BTW, I use Dragger 2 to inject test dependency

Comment: You should print the whole stacktrace. It'll tell you why and where this issues appears from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in code

```
@After
fun validate() {
    validateMockitoUsage()
}
```

The most important you have to you the correct import
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.validateMockitoUsage

Now it's work for me